# How reading data into char array works?

Tags: java, filereader

This is code of copying data of one file into second file

```
      public class Writer 
      {
          public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
          {
              File f=new File("D:/test.txt");
              FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);
              char cbuff[]=new char[100];
              int c=fr.read(cbuff);
              System.out.println(c);
              c=fr.read(cbuff);
              System.out.println(c);
              fr.close();

              FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("D:/newTest.txt");
              fw.write(cbuff);
              fw.close();
          }   
      }
```

The output is 
67
-1 
**My first question is** 
I wanna know that size of char array is 1000 so why does read method returns -1 second time.


**My second question is**
Acc. to [Java Docs] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28java.nio.CharBuffer%29)

> or -1 if this source of characters is at its end

What is the meaning of the above line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanna know that size of char array is 1000 so why does read method returns -1 second time.

Because the input stream contains no more characters to read. Note that if there were a second read, you would overwrite the contents already read into the array.

And your javadoc points to the wrong method. You use [the `read()` method taking a `char[]` as an argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28char%5B%5D%29). A [`CharBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html) is not a `char[]`!

Finally (and you have asked a question about such a subject recently and I have already told you that), you should specify the encoding you are using for both reading the file and writing to the file.

Comment: so this line is true "Since you have only 67 chars, You have read the whole file, so the next time the cursor will be at the end of the file, so it returns -1. in another world there is nothing left to read"

Comment: Yes, that's it. Also notice what I said about the second read. And also note that with the current code, the destination file _will_ be 100 chars long (actual size depending on the encoding), and the rest after char 67 will be filled with zeroes.

Comment: ok I last thing  in case of read method that i pointed out what does this line mean "or -1 if this source of characters is at its end

Comment: Well, here, the char source is a file; which means the reader has reached the end of file without any more characters to read from it. Also do not forget that a `Reader` reads text, which means it reads the bytes then decodes them to chars (again, depending on the encoding used to read the file); and not all byte sequences can translate to chars.

Answer (score 1):

when you do this:

```
fr.read(cbuff);
```

Since you have only `67` chars, You have read the whole file, so the next time the cursor will be at the end of the file, so it returns `-1`. in another world there is nothing left to read.

Comment: ok but in case of read method that i pointed out what does this line mean "or -1 if this source of characters is at its end"

Comment: it means that it will return the number of char that have been read, anther wise it will return -1 if there is no data in the file or its finished reading.

Answer (score 1):

When first time you are reading by **fr.read(cbuff)** then it's reading characters in the file and total char are 67 so it's showing 67 now cursor moves to end of file next time when you are reading then it found **EOF** that's why returning -1.